# python "in" operator reflected magic method

Tags: python

`|` operator has two magic methods, normal and reflected.

```
# object + other
__or__(self, other)
    # Implements bitwise or using the | operator.

# other + object
__ror__(self, other)
    # Implements reflected bitwise or using the | operator.
```

`in` operator only has one magic method.

```
# item in object
__contains__(self, item)
    # __contains__ defines behavior for membership tests using in and not in.
```

---

**How can I implement `in` operator reflected magic method?**

```
# object in sequence
__rcontains__(self, sequence):
    # defines behavior for self in or not in sequence
```

It will be useful when you want to implement sql conditions

```
class Field(object):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return '<', self._value, other

Model.objects.filter(Field('a') > 1)
Model.objects.filter(Field('a') in [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Use `[1, 2, 3, 4] in Field('a')`, or use some method, e.g. `Field('a').is_one_of(...)`

Comment: Django use `fieldname__in==[1, 2, 3, 4]`, SQLAlchemy use `Table.fieldname.in_([1, 2, 3, 4])`.
But I think `Field('a') in [1, 2, 3, 4]` is a better solution, because it is more like normal python code.

Comment: Django and SQLAlchemy do it that way because there's no better way to do it, so...

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because the `in` operator is semantically tied to the definition of what it means for an object to "contain" another. So the operation has to be defined in the container class (here, `list`), not the value (`Field`).

To illustrate, `in` in your case is meant to be used like this:

```
Field('a') in [Field('a'), Field('b'), Field('c')]
```

Which of course is not what you want.

The closest you can get to what you want here is, as you mentioned in the comments, to use something like Django's `fieldname__in==[1, 2, 3, 4]` or SQLAlchemy's `Table.fieldname.in_([1, 2, 3, 4])`. For example, you could add a method to `Field`:

```
Field('a').is_in([1, 2, 3])
```

Another approach would be to create a specific container class so you can write:

```
Field('a') in Values([1, 2, 3])
```

But not only is it more verbose (requires an additional import), I would argue that it's harder to understand what's really happening behind.

This would also work:

```
Field('a') == [1, 2, 3]
```

But again, it feels more "magical" and confusing, because it doesn't respect the semantics of `==`.

Comment: Like you said, My current solution is using  `<<` operator as `in`,   `Field('a') << [1,2,3]`.

Comment: @jdxin0 Don't do that. Use a `in_` or `is_in` method instead. That's infinitely more intuitive.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  Maybe you are right. Searching for a more intuitive way of implementing sql condition "in" is my original intention.